# Draw a smooth expanding circle

Tags: c#, xna

I want to create a sonar ping, where when it is activated a circle emanates from a ship's position. However, if I use a texture and scale it up as the circle gets bigger, the thickness of the circle increases as well, and I've tried to use a spritesheet but the size of the sheet needed to make the expansion look smooth is impractical. How would I go about programming a smooth expanding circle?

Comment: What does the circle look like? Is it a solid color? Or just the outline?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how complicated the shape that you're trying to produce is, you might be able to do it entirely in a pixel shader.  See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2011/10/31/shader-aliasing.aspx) for an example of how to draw very simple anti-aliased circles in this way.